# How to access KEY and VALUE of JSON in PHP, ($obj->Key) and $arr['ID'] not working

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I know there are a lot of different posts asking about the same problem, and I have already tried all of them and still couldn't find a solution. so please feel free to refer me to right answer if there is one.

I am getting a JSON post request from an Ionic 2 application to my PHP server. The attached JSON includes some data from SQLite which I need to insert into my MySQL database using PHP script.

This is how I am accessing the JSON and Processing.

```
    //Make sure that it is a POST request.
if(strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'POST') != 0){
    throw new Exception('Request method must be POST!');
}

//Make sure that the content type of the POST request has been set to application/json
$contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';
if(strcasecmp($contentType, 'application/json') != 0){
    throw new Exception('Content type must be: application/json');
}

//Receive the RAW post data.
$content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));

//Attempt to decode the incoming RAW post data from JSON.
$decoded = json_decode($content,True);

//If json_decode failed, the JSON is invalid.
if(!is_array($decoded)){
    throw new Exception('Received content contained invalid JSON!');
}
```

For test, I am printing my JSON into a file by running the code below

```
$file = 'log.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $decoded);
```

Here is Response I get in log.txt file which is a valid JSON

```
[  
   {  
      "Date":"October 13th 2017, 6:21:32",
      "ID":"20000",
      "Age":1
   },
   {  
      "Date":"October 11th 2017, 7:21:32",
      "ID":"20001",
      "Age":1
   }
]
```

**Problem:**

**How can I assign ID value from the above JSON to a new variable?**

Already tried with no sucdess:

```
$decoded = json_decode($content);
foreach ($decoded as $obj) {
    file_put_contents($file, $obj->ID); 
}

$decodedarray = json_decode($content,True);
foreach ($decodedarray as $arr) {
    file_put_contents($file, $arr['ID']);
}
```

Comment: No clue what you're asking, given you sample data a foreach loop over the array works perfectly fine, see https://3v4l.org/NhZGL

Comment: Looping and using file_put_contents will keep overwriting that one $file, so it may not be resulting in what you expect in the file? Is there a reason you cannot do echos or var_dump to debug the content and array loops directly?

Comment: @CBroe, I am about to pull my hair out. It just doesn't work with the JSON I receive. I noticed your Array has a different syntax ['{}'] the JSON  receive doesn't have a single colon at the beginning and of JSON. maybe that is the reason.

Comment: _"I noticed your Array has a different syntax"_ - no, it doesn't, that's straight up copy&pasted from your example. Of course it needs additional string delimiters around it, to make it a string value in the first place, but that doesn't change anything about data the structure once it is parsed.